How to send a WM_IME_REQUEST message from C#
I'm working on an IME tool. To figure out the caret position of the foreground window, I'm supposed to use SendMessage() to send a  WM_IME_REQUEST (0x0288) message, along with the parameters:

wParam: IMR_QUERYCHARPOSITION (0x0006)
lParam: a pointer to a IMECHARPOSITION structure

The documentation for IMR_QUERYCHARPOSITION notes the return value from SendMessage:

Return Value
Returns a nonzero value if the application fills the IMECHARPOSITION structure. Otherwise, the command returns 0.

However, SendMessage always returns 0. And the ImeCharPosition struct is still zeroed. What's the correct way to send this message?
Minimal code (CMRE)
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    public int left;
    public int top;
    public int right;
    public int bottom;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct POINT
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ImeCharPosition
{
    public int size;
    public int charPos;
    public POINT point;
    public uint lineHeight;
    public RECT rectDocument;
}

public const int WM_IME_REQUEST = 0x0288;
public int IMR_QUERYCHARPOSITION = 0x0006;

void GetCaretPos()
{
    var hwnd = Win32.GetForegroundWindow();
    ImeCharPosition charPos = new ImeCharPosition();
    charPos.size = Marshal.SizeOf(charPos);
    IntPtr charPosPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(charPos));

    try
    {
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(charPos, charPosPtr, false);

        var success = SendMessage(hwnd, WM_IME_REQUEST, (IntPtr)IMR_QUERYCHARPOSITION, charPosPtr);

        Console.WriteLine(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

        if (success == 0) return;

        var charPosition = Marshal.PtrToStructure<ImeCharPosition>(charPosPtr);
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(charPosPtr);
    }
}

To make sure I didn't have issues with my Marshaling, I recreated my code in C++, and am getting the exact same results. i.e. the SendMessage result is 0, and charPos is still zeroed out.
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Winuser.h>

int main()
{
    HWND foreground = GetForegroundWindow();
    UINT32 pid = GetWindowThreadProcessId(foreground, NULL);
    GUITHREADINFO thread_info = {};
    thread_info.cbSize = sizeof(GUITHREADINFO);
    GetGUIThreadInfo(pid, &thread_info);
    HWND hwnd = thread_info.hwndFocus;

    IMECHARPOSITION charPos = {};
    charPos.dwSize = sizeof(IMECHARPOSITION);

    int result = SendMessage(hwnd, WM_IME_REQUEST, IMR_QUERYCHARPOSITION, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&charPos));



The return value of SendMessage() here is used only to report success or failure. The actual data is exchanged through the lParam that points to an IMECHARPOSITION structure.

@IInspectable Oops, should've removed that before posting! Regardless, the struct I pass to lParam is still zeroed out.

You probably need to set set charPos->size to Marshal.SizeOf(charPos)) prior to calling SendMessage().

@Luke Good catch! Alas, no change in output. Code updated.

The following may be of interest: Native interoperability best practices and Windows Data Types.

The structure definitions are slightly wrong, though probably not meaningfully. Regardless, use CsWin32 to get proper definitions. The issue, I believe, is with using the handle returned from GetForegroundWindow(). You'll need to pass that into GetWindowThreadProcessId() and use the thread ID in a subsequent call to GetGUIThreadInfo().

That'll get you a hwndFocus, the currently focused window. Using that as the target in the SendMessage() call will succeed (if it is a text input control that didn't break IME support).

@IInspectable Thanks! I made those changes. The hwnd is almost always the same, but sometimes it isn't! However, SendMessage still doesn't fill the ImeCharPosition struct. What are the errors in the struct definitions? I went over them again, and I'm not seeing any errors.

int is signed, but most fields are DWORDs, i.e., unsigned. There could be issues around structure packing, too.

I see, thanks! To make sure the issue was not with my Marshaling code, I used the same APIs in C++, and I'm getting the exact same result. See edit for C++ code.

For beginning start with EDIT control. At least check that window that you try to interact handles IME (for example using Win+.).

The handle is wrong obviously. For example, the immpad-interim example 's input window is CTextInputCtrl.
